# How to exclude a project from build solution step on Azure DevOps Pipeline

Tags: .net, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a .NET multi project solution like this:

- Solution

  - Project1
  - Project2
  - Project4

I have this solution on our DevOps environment and I created a pipeline that will analyze it using SonarQube (sonar cloud). This pipeline contains the following steps:

- SonarQube Analysis

  - Use NuGet 4.4.1
  - NuGet restore
  - Prepare analysis on SonarQube
  - Build Solution
  - Test Assemblies
  - Run Code Analysis
  - Publish Quality Gate Result

My issue is on the Build Solution step. Some of my projects are reports or sql projects that I want to exclude from this step that are indeed making the build to fail. I have been looking around the internet and tried a couple of things like:

1. Creating a new configuration in the solution that has some projects set not to build
2. Adding "-target:Project1;Project2;" (this caused an error on the pipeline)

I have tried many other things on my end that are not necessarily documented with no luck. Have anyone successfully configured Build Solution inside SonarQube analysis to exclude certain projects from a .NET solution?

Answer (score 0):

As `MSBUILD` only accepts one project specification per build, you will need to have multiple steps, each building a specific project.

Let's say you only want to build projects 1 and 2, and that you are using the [.Net Core task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/dotnet-core?view=azure-devops&tabs=dotnetfive).

You would need to have two steps like so:

```yaml
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: '**/*Project1.csproj'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: '**/*Project2.csproj'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exclude a project from build with MSBuild, you can use the Solution filter files to implement it. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/solution-filters?view=vs-2019

```
{
  "solution": {
    "path": "..\\..\\Documents\\GitHub\\msbuild\\MSBuild.sln",
    "projects": [
      "src\\Build.OM.UnitTests\\Microsoft.Build.Engine.OM.UnitTests.csproj"
    ]
  }
}
```

Besides, you also can use the  .Net Core task to buildprojects one by one as @rogerio said. But please note that if your .NET Core or .NET Standard build depends on NuGet packages, make sure to add two copies of this step: one with the restore command and one with the build command.